# VS Code equivalent code . command for WebStorm which opens the current directory on the editor

Tags: terminal, command, webstorm, visual-studio-code

Is there an equivalent or similar command for [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) like `code .` which automatically opens the directory with the [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor?

Comment: Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the @LazyOne comment telling me to check the [command-line interface](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html) I found the answer [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/opening-files-from-command-line.html).

The most similar command would be:

- In Windows write `> webstorm.bat` to open the editor from the cmd or in case you want to open a project adding the path after it `> webstorm.bat C:\MyProject`
- In macOS, after [creating a launcher script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html) it would be `$ webstorm` to open the editor or in case you want to open a project `$ webstorm ~/MyProject`

Answer (score 0):

```
webstorm .
```

Works in cmd when you are inside a directory.